# Recover overwritten contents from a saved word file in Office 2013 & Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word, data-recovery

My dad wrote a new word file and saved it with a same name to a word file previously saved. Now previous file was overwritten. How can I restore this file and keep the new one as well.

Now the answers to the questions I might be asked -

1. I tried Recuva, **~WRD???.TMP** thing as well but it was of no use.
2. I tried 3 others **Word Regenerator**, **Recover My Files** & **Recovery Toolbox for Word**.
3. I use Office 2013 and Windows 8 Pro 64-bit and in **Office13** I checked there was no previous unsaved versions in **Info -> Versions**
4. In Windows 8 I couldn't find any **restore previous versions in file properties**. I think since its because system restore wasn't on.

Lastly I haven't saved anything on the drive.

Is there anything that I haven't tried or can be done about the issue.

Comment: If the file recovery software cannot recover it then you are out of options. Sounds like you didn't setup file versions before this mistake was made.  You are out of luck.  Office only keeps tracks of versions if its the same file that is modified, your father, replaced the file.  **Simply said the file is lost.**